# Telnet library in C/ C++ Linux that can login telnet server

Tags: c++, c, linux, telnet, telnetlib

Any one aware of a telnet library written in c or c++ (Linux) that I can use to login with password to telnet server?

I got this one, but this is using boost, i I don't want to use boost.

> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1349346/telnet-library-for-c

I want to loging following server and send command: 
198.182.241.14 (hosted by: Pittsburg State University, Kansas, USA) - login: library

Comment: off-topic, try in http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Added link also off topic I think.

Comment: Yes, please follow the link I posted, code recommendation is a way more suited place for this kind of requests.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> https://github.com/seanmiddleditch/libtelnet

This opensource code will help you I think